# Magento 2.3 Extensions on Ubunu 18.04

Tags: php, module, magento2.3, extensions, ubuntu

I installed Magento 2.3 successfully on my Ubuntu Maschine and tried to start to make my first own module. I followed this tutorial: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/.

But I quickly ran into a problem as the php bin/magento module:status command is not working.

The problem is that

> There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.

Any Idea how I can save this problem?

[image]

Comment: just run php bin/magento only and check here you will get errors then solve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check module.xml file of your module which you created at last. This error generally occurs because of this file only.

Comment: you are the best man. i feel so stupid. forgot one space between to words. so sorrrrrrry

Comment: need to wait 10 min or so, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add the permission to Magento **var**, **generated** & **pub** folder. Just hit the below cmd in Magento root directory.

> **sudo chmod -R 0777 pub/* generated/* var/***